# Wordpress SQL query too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

In wordpress, I want to get posts by longitude and latitude, but the server is responding in 20-25 seconds.

```
$querystr = "
SELECT
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( $user_lat ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( pm1.meta_value ) ) + COS( RADIANS( $user_lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( pm1.meta_value ) ) * COS( RADIANS( pm2.meta_value ) - RADIANS( $user_long ) ) ) *3959 AS distance,
pm1.meta_value AS lat, pm2.meta_value AS lon,
p.*
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( p.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON p.id = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key = 'latitude'
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON p.id = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = 'longitude'

WHERE post_type = 'post'
AND post_status = 'publish'
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
";


$results = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
```

Comment: How many rows do you have there? 25 seconds is strange.

Comment: Are you sure that only this query going slow your site? Because for slow site there could be many reason.

Comment: Yes. When i use simple query, everything is ok. For example:
new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=123' );

Comment: This happens due to wordpress's limitation. 100K posts is heavy. Joining that with meta table will make your database suffer. Why not create a custom table instead?

Comment: Ye maybe i have to do it. I was wondering if there is another way. Thank you.